# django x-editable /post URL issue & django model save

Tags: django, save, models, x-editable

I would like to click on the object and change its attribute value and save it by updating object with new attribute value.

I try to achieve it with x-editable however it gives me an issue as per the picture below. I believe it is sth to do with my url defined in main.js script.

Any ideas how can I solve it ? I would like to use django model save function because I use it for other further reasons.

This is when I click on substage value and x-editable jquery works:
[image]

but it does not SAVE new value:
[image]

Terminal returns:

```
[08/May/2016 17:06:03]"POST /post HTTP/1.1" 404 2027
```

Below is part of my templates code:

```
{% for substage in trsubstage.substages_related %}
    {% for zone in zones %}
        {% if zone == substage.stage.zone %}
            <td style="width:40px" align="center">
                <div id="substage">
                    <a href="#" data-pk="{{ substage.id }}" data-type="text" >
                        {{ substage.substage_value }}</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

here is my main.js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';

$('#substage a').editable({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'username',
    url: '/post',
    title: 'Enter username'
    });
});
```

here are my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.MainStatusView.as_view(), name='mainstatus'),
    ]
```

and here is my model Substage:

```
class SubStage(models.Model):
    tablerow_substage = models.ForeignKey(TRSubStage)
    stage = models.ForeignKey(Stage)
    substage_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True)
    created_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s.%s.%s' % (self.stage.zone,
                             self.stage.tablerow_stage.stage_name,
                             self.tablerow_substage.substage_num)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubStage, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.value_original = self.substage_value

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            response = super(SubStage, self).save(**kwargs)
            if self.value_original != self.substage_value:
                substage_log = SubStageLog()
                substage_log.substage = self
                substage_log.substage_value = self.value_original
                substage_log.save()

            return response


class SubStageLog(models.Model):
    substage = models.ForeignKey(SubStage)
    substage_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    update_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True)
    update_time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add= True)


    def __str__(self):
        return '%s | %s | %s' % (self.substage, self.update_date, self.update_time)

# to change str(self.id) to self.slug (but I need to add slug attribute to RoomLog)
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return '/mods/' + str(self.id) + '/'
```

Comment: I have changed the url in main.js file to: url: '', and it does change the value and display it in the table however it does not save the new value. How can I save new value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have a url called "post" in your urls.py so your js functions but the request has no idea where to send your data.

Comment: yes, but the url is part of the problem. the problem is I do not have function in the views to handle data to save it. Any ideas what I should have in my views function to save the changed value of the object ?

Comment: this is what is returned from jquery to django view in request.POST for example: <QueryDict: {u'pk': [u'34'], u'name': [u'username'], u'value': [u'2']}>. How to aply it to my models object save function ?

Comment: Try https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/ for querying and saving objects

Comment: Sorry my phone was not letting me format correctly.
    `yourmodelobject.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('pk'))
    yourmodelobject.value = request.POST.get('value')'
    yourmodelobject.save()`

Comment: I have just had a look into it and follow info in official django website as per your link and it works fine now. Thanks :-)

Comment: Really sorry for the formatting. Its not taking the four spaces or backslashes to put the code in a block

Comment: Your welcome sorry for all the back and forth. Good luck with your project

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

Below is updated code and it works fine now so I can save the value :-)

template:

```
{% for substage in trsubstage.substages_related %}
    {% for zone in zones %}
        {% if zone == substage.stage.zone %}
            <td style="width:40px" align="center">
                <div id="substage">
                    <a href="#" data-pk="{{ substage.id }}" data-type="text" >
{{ substage.substage_value }}</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //toggle `popup` / `inline` mode
    $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';

$('#substage a').editable({
    type: 'text',
    name: 'username',
    url: '/main/dupa/',
    title: 'Enter username'
    });
});
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.MainStatusView.as_view(), name='main'),
    url(r'^dupa/$', views.dupa, name='dupa'),
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def dupa(request):
    if request.POST:
        z = SubStage.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get('pk'))
        z.substage_value = int(request.POST.get('value'))
        z.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/main/')
```